# Tree property and singular strong limit cardinals

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

I heard that the following theorem is proved recently by Foreman-Magidor, which answers a famous old open question:

> **Theorem.** It is consistent, relative to the existence of large cardinals, that there is a singular strong limit cardinal $\kappa,$ such that the tree property hold at both $\kappa^+$ and $\kappa^{++}.$

Here are some questions related to the above theorem:

1) Does anyone know the main idea of the proof?

2) Is the $\kappa$ in the theorem large, or it can be also small, like $\aleph_\omega?$

3) What kind of large cardinal(s) are used in the proof?

4) Are there any notes or slides presenting the proof (as far as I know the paper itself is not written yet, as I asked Magidor for the paper, and did not receive anything).

Comment: This is quite recent, so I don't think there are any tangible material written yet. Yair told me that he figured out a proof just about when Magidor told him that they cracked it; so maybe he could shed some light on the matter.

Comment: So, Magidor is coaxing Foreman back into forcing and large cardinals?

Comment: I think you might be able to watch Dima Sinapova lecturing on the tree property at: https://www.newton.ac.uk/event/hifw01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following theorem from Sinapova's paper ''[THE TREE PROPERTY AT THE FIRST AND DOUBLE
SUCCESSORS OF A SINGULAR](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~sinapova/Single%20and%20double%20successors.pdf)'' answers your main question.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\langle\kappa_{n}:n<\omega\rangle$ is an increasing sequence of super-compact cardinals and that $\lambda$ is a weakly compact cardinal with $\lambda>\sup\{\kappa_n:n<\omega\}$. Then there is a generic extension in which $\kappa_0$ is strong limit singular with $cf(\kappa_0)=\omega$ and $\lambda=\kappa_0^{++}$, and the tree property holds at both $\kappa_0^{+}$ and $\kappa_0^{++}$.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani you're welcome!